# pass xml results using Google Maps Api V3

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As I was working with the google maps api v3, I am running into issues trying to pass the xml file to populate the results on the map.
I checked the php file to see if the xml file is being properly being generated, and it's working.  The php file is in the same directory as my html file.
I think it's failing in the function called downloadUrl.  The status it returns when I'm debugging for request.readyState is 0, then 1.  It seems that it never goes in the request.readyState == 4. Am I doing something wrong here?

The data passed into searchLocationsNear is correct.  The value of center is: `results[0].geometry.location`.

Below are the two functions:

```
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
        var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
        var st = document.getElementById('studyTopicSelect').value;
        /*http://www.icliqz.com/Dev/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=41.7636111&lng=-72.6855556&lat=41.7636111&radius=20&studytopic=GMAT*/

        var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() 
                        +'&lat=' + center.lat() + '&radius=' + radius + '&studytopic=' +st;

        //Fails here. xml file not loading after it's generated.
        downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var username = markers[i].getAttribute("username");
            var studytopic = markers[i].getAttribute("studytopic");
            var distance = markers[i].getAttribute("distance");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                var html = "<b>" + username + "</b> <br/>" + studytopic;
                var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    shadow: icon.shadow
                });
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
        });
    }
```

The second:

```
function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
        else if (request.readyState == 1) {
            request_loading();
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function request_loading() {
    $('#loading').html('<p><img src="/ing/loading.gif" width="43" height="11" /></p>');
    //$('#loading').load("/examples/ajax-loaded.html");
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery - I'd recommend just using the jquery functions for doing the AJAX request, [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  It should make it simpler to then debug where the problem is, using the error() and complete() callback methods.

Comment: Hi duncan.  I'm clearly doing something wrong.  Not sure how to approach this.
'
function getMarkers(searchUrl) {
$.get(searchUrl, function(xml){
$(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
var name = $(this).find('username').text();
map.bounds.extend(point);    
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: point,
map: map
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var html='<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+studytopic;    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infoWindow.setContent(html);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });
 map.fitBounds(map.bounds);
});
});
}
'